# JAX-RS Path Matching

Tags: java, regex, jax-rs

I would like to validate URLs for my REST API. For example I have this JAX-RS Path:

```
/users/{id : \\d+}
```

Now I will test different URLs without starting the server

`/users/1` -> valid

`/users/a` -> not valid

Anybody know an existing solution or possibilty to do it?

**Update:**
I created a method for getting Regex from Path Annotation. But there could be problems when the chars `{`, `}` or `:` are on an unexpected position.

```
private String GetRegex(String patternPath) {
    int indexOfOpen = patternPath.indexOf("{", 0);
    if (indexOfOpen < 0) {
        return patternPath;
    } else {
        int indexOfClose = patternPath.indexOf("}");
        int indexOfRegexStart = patternPath.indexOf(":");
        if (indexOfRegexStart < 0 || indexOfRegexStart > indexOfClose) {
            patternPath = patternPath.substring(0, indexOfOpen) + ".*"
                    + patternPath.substring(indexOfClose + 1, patternPath.length());
        } else {
            patternPath = patternPath.substring(0, indexOfOpen)
                    + patternPath.substring(indexOfRegexStart + 1, indexOfClose).trim()
                    + patternPath.substring(indexOfClose + 1, patternPath.length());
        }

        return GetRegex(patternPath);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
String patternPath = "/users/{userid}/{userId2 : \\d+$}";
String methodPath = "/users/435345/435435";

String getRegex = GetRegex(patternPath);

Assert.assertEquals("/users/.*/\\d+$", getRegex);

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(getRegex).matcher(methodPath);
Assert.assertEquals(true, matcher.matches());
```

Comment: Probably you want to assure there is end of string after it - `/users/{id:\\d+$}`

Comment: Okay it is useful. But my question is, how can I check that the URL `/users/a` is not valid because of the Regex `\\d+$`?

Comment: I am reading with Reflection all Path Annotations in the project and I am trying to validate which rest assured test is matching the Path Annonation

Answer (score 0):

The regex `\d+$` matches 1 to N digits and that the string ends with it. It will not match a characte `a` for example.

You can do your code something like it:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("/users/\\d+$").matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved my method. I am searching now for the template expression with `"/{"` and for the end of template expression with `"}/"`.

```
public String GetRegex(String patternPath) {

    int indexOfOpen = patternPath.indexOf("/{");
    if (indexOfOpen < 0) {
        return patternPath;
    } else {
        int indexOfClose = patternPath.indexOf("}/");
        if(indexOfClose < 0){
            if(patternPath.substring(patternPath.length() - 1).equals("}")){
                indexOfClose = patternPath.length() - 1;
            }
            else{
                return patternPath;
            }
        }

        int indexOfRegexStart = patternPath.indexOf(":", indexOfOpen);
        if (indexOfRegexStart < 0 || indexOfRegexStart > indexOfClose) {
            patternPath = patternPath.substring(0, indexOfOpen + 1) + ".*" + patternPath.substring(indexOfClose + 1, patternPath.length());
        } else {
            patternPath = patternPath.substring(0, indexOfOpen + 1)
                    + patternPath.substring(indexOfRegexStart + 1, indexOfClose).trim()
                    + patternPath.substring(indexOfClose + 1, patternPath.length());
        }

        return GetRegex(patternPath);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
String itemPath = "/users/{userid}/{userId2 : \\d+:{$}/{userid3}/{userid4 : [:]}/{userId5}/{userId6 : [8]}";
String getRegex = GetRegex(itemPath);
Assert.assertEquals( "/users/.*/\\d+:{$/.*/[:]/.*/[8]", getRegex);
```